# UImage not showing iphone 4/5 version

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

So I have the following images:

splash1.png (IPHONE 3)
splash1@2x.png (IPHONE 4)
splash1-568h@2x.png (IPHONE 5)

I want to show the corresponding images in iphone 3, 4, 5.

I tried doing

```
UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"splash1.png"];
self.splashimg.image = img;
[self.splashimg setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
```

Where self.splashimg is an imageview that shoes the image img.

but this still shows the iphone 3 image and does not get the iphone 4 or 5 image.

what can I do?

When I look at the app in iphone 5, I see the splash image but the iphone 3 version of it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no provision in UIKit for a general `-568h@2x` device modifier: it will only work for `Default.png`.

So, this explains why your app is not using the iPhone 5 specific version of your images.

In any case, it should be able to use the `@2x` version of your files, so I would suggest checking that `splash1@2x.png` is there and it is not corrupt or in a wrong format, etc.

You can find an extension to `UIImage` (via a category) to support the use of the `-586@2x` device modifier here: https://gist.github.com/3711077.